# Do URL specifications say that the #anchor must appear after the ?parameters

Tags: url

I've noticed that

https://someurl.com/page.html#anchor?utm_campaign=xyz

Does not correctly find the anchor in the page, but

https://someurl.com/page.html?utm_campaign=xyz#anchor

does work.

I've looked through https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986 and as far as I can see, there's nothing specific about where the #anchor needs to appear, only that the # symbol denotes the anchor in the same way that ? denotes the start of URL params.

So, where would I find in the specifications that it must appear at the end? Or are my browsers secretly non-conformant? I'm asking so that I can provide evidence to a customer one way or another.

Comment: _"Does not correctly find the anchor in the page"_... I think you're mistaken about this. The hash in that URL is `#anchor?utm_campaign=xyz`. What cannot be found in that URL is the query string, at least not without extracting it from the hash

Comment: @Phil thanks. From the specs, I interpreted it as the `?` was a reserved character that would denote the start of the URL params. In any case, can you help me understand where in the specs it specifies how the characters should be interpreted?

Comment: See https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-writing... _"An **absolute-URL-with-fragment string** must be an absolute-URL string, optionally followed by U+0023 (#) and a URL-fragment string."_ TL;DR the fragment must come last

Comment: Excellent, that's it @phil. If you put in an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Link-only answers are not worth posting.